# MySQL structure questions

Tags: mysql

I have a tblClient and tblDirectory.

I want to create a Company adress book in tblDirectory so Client have access to it. Client insert a Company adress one time so they don't have to insert it each time and can select it for shipping purpose.

My structural question:

Different client may have the same company adress contact.

Should I avoid duplicate with storing an array in tblDirectory-ClientID column? Or should I just store data like that so I won't have to vefify from time to time if there is duplicate?

Or probably a totally different way to do! :-)

Thank you!

Comment: For each client store their adress even if duplicates...

Comment: As simple as this! Thanks for your quick reply!
My goal would have been to create a big repository which Admin-Dispatch could use to insert manual pick up. I will create another table for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a respository where multiple users want to synchronize contact information, then avoid duplicates. If not, store them as they are, even I feel there are duplicates.
Imagine two users have the same contact stored and one then thinks "I actually don't want to store the phone number of the headquarters of that company but the subsidiary in Belgium" and you update the data. Should it also update for the other user?

Comment: No, as they don't know each others.

We are a shipping company. We want to offer the customer to create web shipping demand, instead of calling.

So each custumer should have it's own personalized Repository of adresses and contacts.


The biggest constraint is to mix Web with Phone shipping demands